# How can I have SSRS report subscriptions go to a SharePoint folder when not in integrated mode?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS with SQL 2012, and have SharePoint 2010. SSRS *is not* in SP integrated mode. I would like to create a subscription to send reports to a SharePoint folder.

When I use the web path (http://) it says "The path is not valid. The path must conform to Uniform Naming Convention (UNC) format".

When I use the UNC path (change the web path to \ etc), it allows it, but does not write the file.

I have googled, and it sounds like, out of the box, the only way to do this is to have SSRS in integrated mode (which I can't do). Is there a common workaround to this? Maybe push to a network folder and then have SharePoint pull from the network folder somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to email enable the document library where you want to send the file then use this email address to email the SharePoint server and it will store the report in the document library. I've used this technique in the past with a SSRS server not in integrated mode to deliver reports on schedule to SharePoint.

This assumes your SharePoint farm has incoming email configured.

Answer (score 0):

**how to give correct UNC path to ssrs reporting subscription**

goto window

press window key and R

type   \**DEVI**\C$

and enter      --**DEVI** is my local Machine name your PC name will be different

your destination path will be like this formatt.
**\Devi\c$\Users\Abhirup Subba\DestinationFolder**

from there goto specific path you want to save file and copy the whole path to subscription

**make sure your destination folder should give full access to file ..like sharing to everyone..**